# Deleting Components in existing managed package?

Tags: managed-package

We have a managed package which we released previously which has some components(vf page, objects,classes etc).

Now, we have added new components which doesn't hold any dependencies to already package components which we released previously.

We wanted to delete all old components from package and keep package as in upload new version by deleting components released previously.

What is the risk involved, can we delete all previously released components, considering we wanted to migrate all subscribers to new components that we have developed.

Please suggest and advise.

Answer (score 1):

All component not marked as global can be deleted. Before new release, an end to end test of application is suggested to foresee any issues.

Like classes components cannot be marked as deprecated, so what we did is wiped the body of component, keeping the global attributes with a note to not remove from future. And for those components, you could delete controller, helper, CSS files (note: do not delete the design files).

ISV partners use patch orgs to support older version where a very limited metadata is allowed to be deleted. But for a packaging or org, its fine to delete unless its not marked as global.

Comment: suppose if I delete vf page and custom object, will that vf page and object still be functional in subscriber org unless they manually delete it, will subscriber still be able to save details to that object from vf page ?

Comment: Subscribers would get your latest code or changes when they upgrade with the new version package, until that they would be able to use the application properly with older version

Comment: so deleted vf page and its functionality they will still be able to run like before even after upgrade right ?

Comment: no, they would be removed as those were deleted from the upgraded version